# ASTParser equivalent in CDT

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-jdt

I am working on a plugin conversation from jdt to cdt.
Can anyone please tell which class is  equivalent to ASTParser(org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AST) in CDT?

Answer (score 2):

I think do the following:

```java
ITranslationUnit tu = (ITranslationUnit)CoreModel.getDefault().create(file);

IASTTranslationUnit ast = tu.getAST();
```

This [link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/c/c7/CDT_APIs_for_code_introspection.pdf) is a set of slides on the CDT AST (pdf). The [CDT Plug-in Developer Guide](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/guide/dom/index.html) has more information.

Comment: how do I get the function name, start line, and length of the function using ITranslationUnit?